# CSS :hover works only on the lower half of the button

Tags: html, css

The page in question:
http://rainbowdoge.000webhostapp.com

The situation:
I have two buttons in the nav menu on the left side.
The upper one contains a hitbox (black for testing purposes), and an image of a rainbow. The image is changing the opacity on hover.
CSS code for that:

```
.icon {
opacity: 0.6;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.iconHitbox:hover .icon {
opacity: 1;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

There is also an iframe on the page. The iconHitbox changes the iframe's source on click.

The problem:
If I hover over the top half of the button, the opacity doesn't change, as if a hover isn't even detected.

The solution I could think of:
I thought that maybe something else is getting in the way, but no, the setSrc() function works when I click on the upper half of the button.

Comment: you have lot of elements (test1,test2,test3) sitting on top of the targetelement mainPageIcon. use z-index to order the elements properly. otherwise use top on the test elements

Comment: Also, instead of setting negative margins on `#mainPageIcon img`, why not adjust `top` and `left` properties?

Comment: In future please include all code relevant to the question, in the question itself. CSS is pretty meaningless without HTML. Once you fix your page, this question becomes meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your `#test1`, `#test2`, and `#test3` elements are being positioned half way over the rainbow circle. You'll need to move them out of the way.

Comment: correct also check for css property position: absolute;
other element might have this property that is coming over it .

Answer (score 0):

The div with the id "test3" is overlapping with your icon. You can see it in the dev tools of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have `absolute` set. If you remove absolute then adjust positioning you'll be good.

**try:**

```
#mainPageIcon {
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
}

.iconHitbox {
   height: 8vh;
   width: 8vh;
}
```